# MIssing dependency on demo (https://spring.io/quickstart)?

Tags: spring

Executing the steps described here --> https://spring.io/quickstart with gradle
(maven works not becuase of complaining about the jdk version)

The exmaple works only if i add the following line to the dependency:
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'

I start it with

```
/usr/local/gradle-6.3/bin/gradle bootRun
```

I can't believe that the demo is wrong,
but i also don't see what i missed.

Complete build file is -->

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.schaffa'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: You clearly didn't follow the tutorial it clearly states you need to go to https://start.spring.io and add the WEB dependency. You didn't add it.

Comment: yes, that was it :)   ... not a friend of GUIs  *g*